# Which way is better for converting number to string?

Tags: java

Sometimes there is need to change an integer to text.
I often use the following way:

```
"" + myNumber
```

But there is alternative way:

```
Integer.toString(myNumber)
```

Which one is better (performance, readability, safety)? 
Or are those equal?

Comment: A very detailed answer to a very similar question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105406/843804

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend

```
String.valueOf(myNumber)
```

This allows you to to change myNumber to another primitive type - or a Number - later.

```
"" + myNumber
```

should be avoided since :

- it produces clutter bytecode (instanciating a new StringBuffer)
- it does not convey what you wanted to do with myNumber

Answer (score 11):

Integer.toString(myNumber) is the safer way because it throws a malformed exception.

Do not worry about performance at this level. There is an expression: [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

**EDIT after comment**

"3000000000" `> Integer.MAX_VALUE` throw an Exception
"-2900000000" `< Integer.MIN_VALUE` throw an Exception
"OO12345" throw an exception, because it begins with two `O letters`, not zero.

You can also manage radix :

```
String intS = "010101";
System.out.format("Parsing %s gives %d, fail with \"010102\"%n",
    intS,(Integer.parseInt(intS, 2)));
intS = "10CAFE8";
System.out.format("Parsing %s gives %d, fail with \"10CAGE8\"%n",
    intS,(Integer.parseInt(intS, 16)));
```

Output :

```
Parsing 010101 gives 21, fail with "010102"
Parsing 10CAFE8 gives 17608680, fail with "10CAGE8"
```

**EDIT after comment 2**

Look in  [Effective Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683) and search for *StringBuilder()* to understant how to replace '`+`' usage.

At execution time, a '`+`' create something like this code :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(123);
sb.toString();
```

This code is better :

```
final int a = 123;
Integer.toString(a);
```

Look at Java code of `Integer.toString(a);`
In Eclipse : `CTRL+rightClick` on `toString()` print the Java code . Give the `src.zip` path in SDK directory if it not already done.
And compare with `StringBuilder.append(int);`

Comment: How can an integer be malformed?

Comment: @FelixDombek I've edited my post to give samples.

Comment: Your examples are about String to Int, but the question is about Int to String.

Comment: @FelixDombek Exact, I compelte my post. Sorry not to be a good english reader.

Comment: @FelixDombek `Effective Java` is a reference to write good code, Is the response you needed? Many other things to know are also inside this book.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they were equally as good. I prefer to use

```
Integer.toString(myNumber)
```

as I find it explains the transition better

Comment: haha my mistake @palacsint